# How to open my apps audio player to play audio after clicking an audio link which is present in email?

Tags: iphone, audio, ios6

I am working on iphone application which plays audio in app.

I can share audio links via email. The person with whome I have shared link can listen to audio by clicking on audio link in the email.

What I need is, when user will click on audio link in email it should open my application and start playing in my apps audio player(if my app is already installed on the device). if app is not installed prompt user to download my app.

How to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you will need to register your own URL scheme for your app. Read Apples [Implementing Custom URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) on how to do this.

But you can not make iOS prompt to install you app, since the OS does not know about you app.
What you could do is always open a website which will try to open your by its URL sheme and it this fails present the use a webpage that offers them to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/. I hope it will be helpful.

About showing a prompt what you can do is always put your app's app store link in email saying "Please install app using below link if you don't have app installed on your device" or some other meaningful message you can have. Link will redirect user to app store page where user can install the app.